# Spring Boot: spring.jpa.show-sql vs spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In `Spring Boot` about *Application Properties* about JPA/Hibernate in the `application.properties` file is possible use:

- `spring.jpa.show-sql`
- `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql`

Practically both do the same, so when is mandatory use one over the other?

**Observation:**

In the [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties) page
appears the former explicitly as [spring.jpa.show-sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.jpa.show-sql) and the latter *appears* indirectly through [spring.jpa.properties.*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.jpa.properties)